# writing 8086 assembly program that uses INT 21H in dos

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

**I need to write 8086 assembly program that do the following :** 
-Reads 2 numbers from the keyboard 
-Display the summation of those numbers

**The hints I got till now :** 
The keyboard will store the ASCII code in a register & I will read it 
I need to use some ISR(interrupt service routine ) called **INT 21H**

**The tools I will use :** 
Microsoft assembler

**An example of the code template is :**

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
.exit 
.end
```

, note `.exit` is equivalent to

```
mov AH,4CH
INT 21H
```

My question is how to do it , the assembler doesn't have any GUI , don't know how to compile it and make .exe from it , in general can you solve it with explain ??

Comment: Is this homework? If so, your professor should have given you some instructions on how to operate your assembler. If not, what tutorial are you following?

Comment: yes it's , I don't follow any tutorial , feel lost ...

Comment: You must be following something, since you have a code template here, and you have a specific assignment. What reference material are you using? I don't have a copy of a DOS-era microsoft assembler, so without seeing your materials I can't really give you instructions, but I might be able to point out where your materials give you instructions

Comment: He refused giving us materials , all I got is lecture notes .....

Comment: he also guided us to this book http://ebookee.org/The-Intel-Microprocessors-8086-8088-80186-80188-80286-80386-80486-Pentium-and-Pentium-Processor-Architecture-Programming-and-Interfacing_182496.html

Comment: probably best to ask your professor how to invoke the assembler then - or at least give version information for your microsoft assembler. :/

Comment: I must deliver it on Monday , I also found that I need to use ml.exe in visual studio

Comment: The prof is listening to Pink Floyd on his tube amplifier.  Best not disturb him until Monday.

Comment: I've reached this :http://www.sce.carleton.ca/~mmacleod/masm.html

Comment: and this :http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/vsasm.html

Answer (score 2):

The executable is called `ml.exe` and is typically invoked from the command prompt, although your GUI may automatically invoke it if you name your source file with an `.asm` extension.

It will try to assemble your source file into an object file and then invoke the linker to create an executable from the object file. Use `ml /?` to get a list of options.

Comment: @xsari3x INT 09H is key press